# N/A for Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to match plate appearances for players from one excel sheet to another

```
      A                  B                            C           D     E
 1 Name          Where to Place Formula             Name         Team   PA
 2 AJ Ellis           x                             AJ Ellis     LA     327
 3 AJ Pollock         y                             AJ Pollock   AZ     430
```

My Vloopup function in B2 is `=VLOOKUP(A2,C1:E3,3,FALSE)` and I'm getting an 'N/A'

Comment: Whether it is visibly obvious or not, there **must** be some difference between C2 and A2. Copy C2 into A2 and if your vlookup works then hit ctrl+Z and closely examine both.

Comment: A common cause are extra leading or trailing spaces, formula is fine otherwise.

Comment: Hm, you literally saying you are looking at another worksheet, than the formula is actually wrong and should include the sheets reference. Right now you are looking at the exact same sheet as your formula is on resulting in 'N/A'

Answer (score 0):

So, if the data is on Sheet 2 and the vlookup is on sheet 1 then this works:
[image]

If you have trouble, you can build it on one sheet then cut/paste the data in cells C1:E3 onto the second sheet, the vlookup will change to reflect that move.